# Замена пропусков в DataFrame, по условию и в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame train, в столбце 'Healthcare_1' необходимо заполнить пропуски модой для этого столбца, но для определенного "DistrictId", пробую:

```
for i in range(train['DistrictId'].max()):
    health_mode = train.loc[(train.DistrictId == i), 'Healthcare_1'].mode()[0]
    train.loc[(train.DistrictId == i)].fillna(health_mode, inplace=True)
```

получаю 2 ошибки:
1) .mode()[0] !!! также пробовал float(health_mode)
2) пытаюсь изменить срез !!! пробовал df.update

Comment: Если вы ждёте ответа, то приведите пример датафрейма, с которым можно было бы работать. И выражайтесь яснее - из вашей фразы про ошибки вообще ничего не понятно.

Comment: [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)